# Licensing access to a website

Tags: php, security, authorization

I was wondering if there's a way to control access to a website on a similar way than app licensing works, allowing only given computers on the entire Internet to access them... I can't find a way to uniquely identify a given computer OR to discard all machines except the authorized ones... I don't want a user/password approach as it can be shared.

Comment: Sorry about my language (english is not my first language) if I'm not articulated enough to translate my ideas from thoughts to written words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option here is SSL certificates. Get the client to send you a certificate signing request, sign it with your custom CA, and give them a certificate to use to connect to you with. Ensure that it ties directly to a particular hostname, the hostname of the system. Not entirely fool proof, but better.

Comment: Hmm... it could be a nice solution but it seems a little complicated and not very user-friendly... It's a nice starting point, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses change. MAC addresses can be spoofed. Computer names are set by the user, and computers can change locations, operating systems, hardware components, and owners.

There's a reason that the username/password combination is so prevalent on the web. And, personally, if it's secure enough for Google, it's secure enough for me.

Comment: I was wondering if some sort of licensing scheme could be deployed to protect the server's content and access... The user/password scheme can work to isolate users but I'm looking more into a client-as-station alternative. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the access by IP restriction or mac address restriction. Http server such as apache have access control modules. You can find more information about it from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html